# Problems with header and footer in documentclass book

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I tried to use a header and footer layout I found here on this website. But I have some problems with changing the code to what I want. I want the pagenumbering to be like page x of y in the footer. It would be nice with this layout (just with page x of y instead of just page x):

```
\cfoot{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hrulefill\kern-0.6ex\raisebox{-0.5ex}{$\Bigl[$\makebox[2em][c]{\thepage}$\Bigr]$}\kern-0.5ex\hrulefill}}
```

But the pagenumbering is in the header and there aren't a space between the letters and the numbers as you can see in my minimal work example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}%generelt
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all headers and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove rule between header and text
\fancyhead[LE, RO]{\thepage of \pageref{LastPage}} % put page number in left header on even pages,
                            % right header on odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} % remove uppercase on chapter title
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % remove "Chapter N." prefi
\usepackage{lastpage}
```

Another problem is that I would like to have a chapter numbering in the header. The design is really nice, but I would like to have the chapter number too, just like "CHAnumber| name of the chapter".

Is it possible to make this two changes? And how? Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Instead of using `fancyhdr`, how about `scrlayer-scrpage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate solution with `scrlayer-scrpage`. Thanks @Pouya for providinig the solution for the footer, i copied that.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\headmark}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\footy{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hrulefill\kern-0.6ex\raisebox{-0.5ex}{$\Bigl[$\makebox[\widthof{1.2{\thepage\,
of \pageref{LastPage}}}][c]{\thepage\, of \pageref{LastPage}}$\Bigr]$}\kern-0.5ex\hrulefill}}
%Thanks to Pouya
\cfoot[\footy]{\footy}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: a sample output]

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tweaks of your own code. Does it satisfies what you need?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}                           
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\cfoot{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hrulefill\kern-0.6ex\raisebox{-0.5ex}{$\Bigl[$\makebox[\widthof{\thepage\, of \pageref{LastPage}}][c]{\thepage\, of \pageref{LastPage}}$\Bigr]$}\kern-0.5ex\hrulefill}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\section{Section Title}

\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

[image]